# ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection with postgresql on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, amazon-web-services

When I got my database.yml configured like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  <<: *default
  host: my_db_address
  port: 5432
  database: my_db_name
  username: my_db_user_name
  password: my_db_password

< test and development ommited >
```

When I establish connection like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
```

it says `ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified - 'production'`

It works hovewer If I do it like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    {:adapter => 'postgresql',
     :database => 'my_db_name',
     :host => 'my_db_address',
     :port => '5432',
     :username => 'my_db_user_name',
     :password => 'my_db_password'}
)
```

I'd rather load the config from database.yml. How do I do this?

I'm on Rails 4.2.1 and Postgres 9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
db_config = YAML.load_file('config/database.yml')
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_config['production'])
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply pass your production environment as an option:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:production)
```

Comment: What should be under :production?

Comment: it's reference to your production configuration you set in database.yml

Comment: If I do it this way it says there is no adapter set

Comment: It does work actually https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling/establish_connection